# Setting Custom Adapter to a Layout

Tags: android, listview, mono, xamarin

I am new to creating custom listviews.  I've created a new adapter, but would like to set its adapter layout to one of my own.  How would I change this method to select my own layout file?  I would be grateful for an example.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView; 
    if (view == null) 
        view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, null);
    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = items[position];
    return view;
}
```

Comment: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: `Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1` is ID of layout file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to develop a custom adapter for a listview,

1)your activity must extend `ListActivity`.

2)second,you must have a listview which has the id "list".

3)you should have a layout for your rows. it should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="22px"
        android:layout_height="22px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

4) your main activity should be like

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

that should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(R.Layout.my_list_item, null);